# React & MobX - To use React's state with MobX is anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

In most cases, I use `observable` with `observer()` in React components instead of React's state.

However, to use React's state with MobX is anti-pattern? For example, is this below anti-pattern?

```js
@observer
class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  render() {
     return <button onClick={this._handleClick}>{count}</button>
  }

  _handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prev => {count: prev.count + 1});
  };
}
```

I know it can be replaced with `observable` but I wonder if it is an anti-pattern.

Or, is it better to use `observable` than to use React's state in observed components? if so, why?

Answer (score 0):

The question is why do you have `observer` there since your component isn't using any observables. You won't gain anything here and you can drop it.

And generally, don't worry about anti-patterns much. As long as something works for you, it's totally fine. Don't let others force you into their opinionated patterns.

Comment: In that code, if `observer` does not exist, I have to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` or use `React.PureComponent`.
I'm wondering if I should use `observable` in observed component

Comment: Please read through https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html?